# how to get the result of "print" into a String variable

Tags: python, string, printing

I have a dictionary in python, whose content does not really matter in this question.

The point is that when I do:

```
print (dictionary)
```

I would like to get the result of print into a String variable, something like:

```
my_string = (print(dictionary))
```

I know the above code doesn't have any sense but I just want to show what I am trying to do.

Solution: str (dictionary)

Comment: `my_string = str(dictionary)`?

Comment: um, why not `my_string = str(dictionary)`??? All `print` does is take the output of `str` and *prints it to stdout as a side effect*.

Answer (score 2):

`print(obj)` just calls `str(obj)` and writes it to the `sys.stdout`.

If you want to get hold of the same stringified representation, then you can just call `str` manually:

```
my_string = str(dictionary)
```

[Source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print)

---

Additionally, `str(obj)` just calls `obj.__str__()`, so you can get the same behaviour if you do:

```
my_string = dictionary.__str__()
```

Interesting point: When you create your own class, you can actually override the default implementation of `__str__` and define how you want your instance to be stringified/shown

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the dictionary to a `str` object, which will call its `__str__` method:

```
>>> dictionary = {"foo": "bar"}
>>> my_string = str(dictionary)
>>> print(my_string)
'{"foo":"bar"}'
```

In fact, the `str` cast is useless here, since `print(dictionary)` would call `dictionary.__str__` as well.

Comment: This was so obvious but I'm new in Python, I didn't know I could do this straightly. Thanks to everyone.